# Power of 2 & 5 in product of consecutive numbers

Tags: prime-factorization, products

Is there any way to calculate the powers of 2 and 5 in a product of consecutive $n$ numbers, if given $l$ and $r$.

i.e Suppose $x = l \times (l+1) \times (l+2) \times ...... \times (r-1) \times r$, Then if $x = 2^{p_1}.3^{p_2}.5^{p_3}.7^{p_4}....$, So I am interested a direct way of calculating $p_1$ and $p_3$ with just $l$ and $r$

I am just curious about it. I just want $2$ & $5$, but if there is a general solution for any prime number, It would be great if you mention that.

Comment: Hint:  the order of a prime $p$ in $n!$ is $\lfloor \frac np\rfloor + \lfloor \frac n{p^2}\rfloor +\lfloor \frac n{p^3}\rfloor +\cdots$.

Comment: @lulu , I am not sure I get it because for $10! = 3628800$ ,so the order of prime number $2$ is $\lfloor \frac{3628800}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{3628800}{4} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{3628800}{8} \rfloor + .. $ rather than $\lfloor \frac{10}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{10}{4} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{10}{8} \rfloor$

Comment: @lulu So the answer will be order of prime $p$ in $r!$ - order of prime $p$ in $l!$ .. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: In your first comment...no, it should be $10$ in the numerator.  Easy to prove, see e.g. [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicity_of_Prime_Factor_in_Factorial).  For your second comment...this method is awfully easy, hard to imagine a better one.

Comment: Also:  you should use $(l-1)!$, not $l!$.

Comment: @lulu my second comment is based on the assumption that my first comment is right ! So now that it is established that my first comment is wrong. This is easy enough !

Comment: Ha.  Fair enough.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, silly mistake and For the answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, us define the product of first $n$ integers by $n!$.

Now,highest power of prime $p$ contained in $n!$ is given by-

$$p_{\text{highest power}}=\lfloor\frac{n}{p^1}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n}{p^2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n}{p^3}\rfloor+...+\lfloor\frac{n}{p^n}\rfloor$$ where $p^n\leq n$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function.

For more information see this-[De Polignac's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula).